# Create grouped items within swimlane on D3.js timeline chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have used an example from @cezar from this post, which is excellent [Create a scale for bands with different width in D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560820/create-a-scale-for-bands-with-different-width-in-d3-js/56700057?noredirect=1#comment119070080_56700057)
. I have added a brush in to move the timeline and changed the svg to be responsive, but the code is pretty much the same.

**Issue**

I want to have certain activities appear on the same line if they are the same activity name, so in each swimlane the activities would be grouped.

I assume I need to group at the offset first to get the correct row count, but can get this working at all.

```
const offset = [0]
data.forEach(function (d) {
  const act = d3.group(d, (a) => a.activity);
  console.log([...act].length);
  this.push([...act].length);
}, offset);
```

Here is a fiddle I have created with the changes made. I have put an explanation in the fiddle too, and also attached an image to explain the desired result.

Fiddle: [Timeline Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alketraz/push07xn/)

Image of result: [image]

Hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have got it to work, although I'm pretty sure I've made it far too complicated from what it could have been. Feels like I have too many **.each** iterations and way too much code.

I've also not used d3.js to group by multiple fields, but javascript that I found elsewhere. Here is the sorting by multiple fields.

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function (props) {
  var arr = this;
  var partialResult = {};

  arr.forEach((el) => {
    var grpObj = {};

    props.forEach((prop) => {
      grpObj[prop] = el[prop];
    });

    var key = JSON.stringify(grpObj);

    if (!partialResult[key]) partialResult[key] = [];

    partialResult[key].push(el);
  });

  var finalResult = Object.keys(partialResult).map((key) => {
    var keyObj = JSON.parse(key);
    keyObj.values = partialResult[key];
    return keyObj;
  });

  return finalResult;
};

let data = projects.groupBy(["group", "activity"]);
data = d3.group(data, (d) => d.group);
```

However, it is working, albeit the overlapping issue I mentioned, which I was expecting. This is not a biggie as I can manage this is the data.

If anyone is able to work out how to deal with the overlapping that would be good. Seems like it is just a case of using the grouping section above and rename an activity to **mySql_2**, for example.

Thanks again to the code samples that got me started with this and the advice on how to resolve the issue.

Here is the updated fiddle. I have made the fill opacity 0.5 so that you can clearly see the overlapping.

Fiddle: [D3.js Timeline Gantt_v2](https://jsfiddle.net/alketraz/4ba8m12x/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You should revise your **data model**:

By now, you have "*projects*" (or "*activities*") and "*groups*", and you render them using **scaleBand** (grouping projects within groups). **That model is wrong**.

What you need to do, it first *aggregate* your projects (by the `group` attribute) into another array of objects (let's call them *groupedActivities*).
Now, you have the following data hierarchy:

**Groups** (database, frontend) -> **Grouped Activities** (mySql, Postgres) -> **Activities** (mySql.1, mySql.2) e.t.c

Now you render them the similar way, expcept activities (their Y position is defined by the parent object, and X by the start/end time)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll take another look at this, I was trying to group by the two parts and the model was nested as above. but couldn't get the logic in the rect creation to work. I'll try and put another fiddle up and see how it goes from there.